# Incremental OAuth consent with Microsoft Graph api

Tags: api, azure, oauth-2.0, office365, microsoft-graph-api

We have an app in Azure AD that uses the Microsoft Graph API. The app is working successfully using 4 basic permissions: email, profile User.Read User.ReadBasic.All

These permissions let normal users(non-admins) OAuth authenticate into our app.

We are now building a feature for admin users that lets them see their groups. The groups scope requires admin consent as per: http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes

The sticky point is that if I add the Group.Read.All permission under delegated permissions in Azure AD, this causes normal users to be able to login with the dreaded error "AADSTS90093: Calling principal cannot consent due to lack of permissions".

I have tried manually crafting OAuth authorize urls that explicitly request the scope, but that did not work either. Here is a sample url I used:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fl.xxxxxx.com%3A50000%2Fauth%2Fmicrosoft_graph%2Fcallback&client_id=xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Femail%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fprofile%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FUser.Read%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FUser.ReadBasic.All%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FGroup.Read.All
```

How can I require basic permissions for all users but have admins request additional permissions later on in the application?

Some resources I've already reviewed to no avail:

- http://www.mikepackdev.com/blog_posts/2-Dynamically-Requesting-Facebook-Permissions-with-OmniAuth
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-v2/
- [Switching between web and touch interfaces on Facebook login using Omniauth and Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518101/switching-between-web-and-touch-interfaces-on-facebook-login-using-omniauth-and-r)
- https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/143
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure AD V2.0 endpoint already support **incremental and dynamic consent**. You can register the app to use Azure AD V2.0 authentication endpoint from [here](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/Disambiguation?ru=https%3a%2f%2fapps.dev.microsoft.com%2f).

We can provide two buttons for normal users and admin to login in. Here are the steps using V2.0 endpoint for normal users to login for your reference:

1.sign in and get OAuth Code:

```
GET: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientId}&scope=openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FMail.ReadWrite%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FUser.ReadBasic.All%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FUser.Read&response_type=code+id_token&&redirect_uri={redirectUri}&nonce=678910
```

2.Request for the Access token

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id={clientId}&scope=openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FMail.ReadWrite%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FUser.ReadBasic.All%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FUser.Read
&code={codeFromPreviousRequest}&redirect_uri={RedirectUri}&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret={client_secret}
```

And for the admin to login in, we just add the additional scope with above request. Here are some helpful articles about this topic:

[What's different about the v2.0 endpoint?](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-compare/#new-app-registration-portal)

[v2.0 Protocols - OpenID Connect](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oidc/#protocol-diagram---token-acquisition)
[v2.0 Protocols - OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code/#request-an-authorization-code)

Comment: I paid for Microsoft support and they said the same thing. Its too bad this isn't possible with v1 endpoint and v2.0 has lots of limitations currently. But this does seem like the way forward.